# Invalid Number ORA-01722

Tags: sql, oracle

I have problem in my query that I always get this kind of error

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Whatever I try to doesn't work.
The query is here

```
  SELECT * FROM 
            (
            SELECT p.ProjectID, p.CustomName, p.Name
                FROM projects p
                INNER JOIN 
                    users u
                ON
                    u.UserID =  1
                WHERE 
                    u.User_roleID = 1
            UNION
            SELECT p.ProjectID, p.CustomName, p.Name 
                FROM projects  p
                WHERE 
                    (p.Responsible_person_id = 1 OR p.Delivery_contact = 1) 
                AND 
                    (SYSTIMESTAMP BETWEEN TO_DATE(p.StartDate,'YYYY-MON-DD') AND TO_DATE(p.EndDate,'YYYY-MON-DD'))
                AND 
                    p.status = 2
            UNION
            SELECT rs.ProjectID, pr.CustomName, pr.Name 
                FROM 
                    responsible_persons rs
                LEFT JOIN 
                    projects pr 
                ON 
                    pr.ProjectID = rs.ProjectID
                WHERE 
                    rs.UserID = 1
                AND 
                    (SYSTIMESTAMP BETWEEN TO_DATE(pr.StartDate,'YYYY-MON-DD') AND TO_DATE(pr.EndDate,'YYYY-MON-DD'))
                AND 
                    pr.status = 2
            UNION
            SELECT p.ProjectID, p.CustomName, p.Name 
                FROM project_users_schedule_dates pusd
                LEFT JOIN projects p 
                ON
                    p.ProjectID = pusd.ProjectID
                WHERE pusd.UserID = 1
                AND
                 (SYSTIMESTAMP BETWEEN TO_DATE(pusd.StartDate,'YYYY-MON-DD')
                AND 
                 TO_DATE(pusd.EndDate, 'YYYY-MON-DD'))
                AND
                    p.status = 2) a
       -- GROUP BY a.ProjectID
        ORDER BY a.CustomName, a.ProjectID
```

Since here `StartDate` and `EndDate` are `VARCHAR2` I need to convert to_date but I have no idea what is wrong that I always get error.
The format which I store date is `'YYYY-MM-DD'`
Where I made mistake ? What is wrong here ?

Comment: **Never** store DATE (or timestamp) values in `varchar` columns.

Comment: What data types are `userid` and `status` ?

Comment: I know that this is big mistake, and It's not my failer.  My coleague how install Oracle SQL  and tables made this mistake. I alredy how that this is very very big mistake

Comment: Status is NUMBER, UserID is NUMBER as well

Comment: Yes, it's 3 th line end. It's exactly the end of first SELECT statment

Comment: On a more general note, you've got a `UNION` of four (at a quick glance) separate blocks... try the query with only one at a time to help pin down which one is causing the problem.

Comment: *The format which I store date is 'YYYY-MM-DD'*, but the query uses `'YYYY-MON-DD'`.

Comment: What about the columns `Responsible_person_id` and `Delivery_contact`?

Comment: Only first one works, 2 and 3 and 4 SELECT doesnt work.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I see this error and I  correct it but still have problem. The correct format is YYYY-MM-DD‚

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Responsible_person_id VARCHAR and Delivery_contact also VARCHAR

Comment: Can you simplify it down to the simplest example that reproduces the issue? e.g. just one query of one column of one table, with sample data?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson What do I need to know ? You need all data from these tree tables or .. ?

Comment: I mean a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). At the moment it looks like you have dumped a whole non-working query into the question without trying to narrow down the problem first. The `UNION`s aren't part of the issue, for example, and neither is the `responsible_persons` table.

Comment: I solve the problem. The problem was that Resposible_person_Id was store as VARCHAR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Responsible_person_id VARCHAR and Delivery_contact also VARCHAR

Then compare them with strings, not with numbers.

```
(p.Responsible_person_id = '1' OR p.Delivery_contact = '1')
```

If you compare them to numbers, Oracle tries to convert the column values to a number and the error indicates that not all values in at least one of those columns are proper numbers.

If they are supposed to contain numbers, they should be defined with the `NUMBER` type.